# Проблемы с экспортом данных в Excel

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что делать если при экспорте данных в экслель с TXT файла, нарушается табуляция в дате в экселе?

Comment: В .txt даты нет, там текстовое значение из 8 цифр. Так мы видим на рисунках. Почему выводится в Excel с разделением? Возможно, то, что видим, совсем не то, что есть на самом деле. Нужно видеть "живые" данные.

Comment: а что нужно сделать, чтобы эксель распознавал её как дату?

Comment: *Нужно видеть "живые" данные*

Comment: живые данные в txt

Comment: Да на картинках они, "мертвые"! Покажите данные, которые можно "пощупать". Пример данных в `.txt` и пример загрузки в `Excel`

Comment: а как показать?